# Do I need a storage (of some sort) when pulling data in Azure Data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

*Data newbie here *

Currently, to run analytics report on data pulled from Dynamics 365, I use Power BI.
Issue with this is, Power BI is quite slow processing large data. I carry out a number of transform steps (e.g. Merge, Join, deleting or renaming columns, etc). So, when I try to run a query in Power BI with said steps, it takes a long time to complete.

So, as a solution, I decided to make use of Azure Data Factory(ADF). The plan is to use ADF to pull the data from CRM (i.e. Dynamics 365), perform transformations and publish the data. Then I'll use Power BI for visual analytics.

My question is:
What azure service will I need in addition to Data Factory? Will I need to store the data I pulled from CRM somewhere - like Azure Data Lake or Blob storage? Or can I do the transformation on the fly, right after the data is ingested?

Initially, I thought I could use the 'copy' activity to ingest data from CRM and start playing with the data. But using the copy activity, I needed to provide a sink (destination for the data. Which has to be a storage of some sort).
I also thought, I could make use of the 'lookup' activity. I tried to use it, but getting errors (no exception message is produced).

I have scoured the internet for a similar process (i.e. Dynamics 365 -> Data Factory -> Power BI), but I've not been able to find any.

Most of the processes I've seen however, utilises some sort of data storage right after data ingest.

All response welcome. Even if you believe I am going about this the wrong way.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things here:

- The copy activity just moves data from a source, to a sink. It doesnt modify it on the fly.
- The lookup activity is just to look for some atributes to use later on the same pipeline.
- ADF cannot publish a dataset to power bi (although it may be able to push to a streaming dataset).

You approach is correct, but you need that last step of transforming the data. You have a lot of options here, but since you are already familiar with Power Bi you can use the Wrangling Dataflows, which allows you to take a file from the datalake, apply some power query and save a new file in the lake. You can also use Mapping Dataflows, databricks, or any other data transformation tool.

Lastly, you can pull files from a data lake with Power Bi to make your report with the data on this new file.

Of course, as always in Azure there are a lot of ways to solve problems or architect services, this is the one I consider simpler for you.

Hope this helped!